# React Native fetch or axios failing after I add a property to the json being returned

Tags: javascript, react-native, fetch, axios

So the get call to my API fails when I add a property to the json being returned from the endpoint or when the response content-length exceed 1025.

in axios it returns:
java.io.IOException ID1ID2: actual 0x00001fef != expected 0x00001f8b

in fetch it returns:
Network request failed

The REST client I use works unbelievably.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it because the server responds without gzip content even though without transfer-encoding it returns as gzipped